# Selecting tableView sections Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I am trying to select tableView cells inside of a tableView section in the newest Xcode 12. Before I downloaded the update, selecting and editing cells worked perfectly fine. Are there new methods that need to be called that allows users to do this? Or is this a bug? Has anyone had this happened to them?

Comment: Cell selection works the same. The rules about adding subviews to cells are more strictly enforced, but other table view features are still in place (and there are some new features of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` inside of all of the cells individually worked